# Weird fluctuations in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, numerics, warning-messages

I have a really long multi parameter Lorentzian function:

```
f = (38.4 g1^2 g2^2 Sqrt[κ2^2])/(16 g2^4 (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (1/100 - 4 ω^2) + (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (κ2/100 + 4 ω^2))) + (9.6 g1^2 (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2))/(16 g2^4 (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (1/100 - 4 ω^2) + (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (κ2/100 + 4 ω^2))) + (12.02 (16 g2^4 + 8 g2^2 (κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (1 + 4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2)))/(16 g2^4 (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (1/100 - 4 ω^2) + (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (κ2/100 + 4 ω^2)))
```

with the parameters: `g1`,`g2`,`ω`,`κ2`. I intend to do a density plot with `x = g2`, `y = ω`, and `z = f` with fixed values of `g1` and `κ2`:

```
DensityPlot[(f/.{g1->10,κ2->10}),{g2,0,20},{ω,-25,25},AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotRange->All,PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

And I'm returned with[image]
The shape of the curves are as predicted. Notice that when `g2 = 20`there is a smooth transition in gradient intensity between the blue and yellow. However, near `g2 = 0`the curves appear to be box-shaped with crosses along the line. I suspect that it's a numerical error. I further plotted it with a smaller `g2` range:

```
DensityPlot[(f/.{g1->10,κ2->10}),{g2,0,5},{ω,-25,25},AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotRange->All,PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

[image]
It's clear that there must be some kind of numerical error or instability in the curves, but I'm unsure of how to remedy this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why haven't you already tried to increase the `PlotPoints` setting?

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. I'm an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: To help maintain precision, use `Rationalize` and `Simplify` in the definition of `f`. Compare `LeafCount /@ {f, f // Rationalize // Simplify}`. In addition to or instead of increasing `PlotPoints` you could increase `MaxRecursion`.